# Is there an IronRuby lib for generating concrete CLR classes?

Tags: xaml, ironruby

I want to expose a class to CLR classes.  The reason I have is Xaml.  I want to write WPF custom controls in Ruby, then use xaml to style and provide templates for them.  Last time I tried, Xaml couldn't look up IronRuby types.

```
class NavBar < TreeView
    ...
end

<ControlTemlate TargetType={x:Type MyNamspace:NavBar}>
    ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

I know I can get there by writing to the CodeDom, but I'm hoping someone already did the heavy lifting or can show me how *without* resorting to CodeDom.

Comment: I don't know what the status of the project is or whether it would meet your needs, but Ivan Porto Carrero did some work on IronRuby with WPF for his forthcoming book.  It's available for preview at http://www.manning.com/carrero/, or you might be able to contact him via his blog at http://flanders.co.nz/.  Also I think they did some changes with WPF dynamic lookup as part of WPF 4, though I don't know whether that affected type resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the IronRubyInline project which does exactly that.
For WPF you don't need C# classes though because databinding just works, but for Silverlight < v4 you do need them. 
http://github.com/rvernagus/IronRubyInline